# Flutter form Validate only works for first time

Tags: forms, validation, flutter

I am using flutter forms for login and registration forms. No issue on the `TextFormField` but when I call the function to submit the form below is the issue I face.

1. All things work for the first time, i.e. when I click the submit button for the first time.
2. If I Click the submit button for the second time in the registration form, out of 4 form fields with all having null / blank values, only two shows error.
3. If I click for the 3rd time and onwards, there are no errors and the form is submitted to the server with null / blank data.

I tried to print the `_formKey.currentState.validate()` and below is the result for the same.

```
flutter:  form current State : false
flutter:  form current State : true
flutter:  form current State : true
flutter:  form current State : true
flutter:  form current State : true
flutter:  form current State : true
flutter:  form current State : true
flutter:  form current State : true
flutter:  form current State : true
```

below is the code for the first few lines where the validation is checked !

```
print(" form current State : ${_formKey.currentState.validate()}");
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      // No error in validation
      setState(() {
        _formKey.currentState.save();
        _isLoading = true;
      });
...
}
```

what am I doing wrong here ?

below is the `validator code` for `name` field and is same for all with only `regex` changing...

```
validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty && !errors.contains(kNameNullError)) {
          setState(() {
            errors.add(kNameNullError);
          });
          return "";
        } else if (!nameValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value) &&
            !errors.contains(kInvalidNameError)) {
          setState(() {
            errors.add(kInvalidNameError);
          });
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
```

Comment: can you also provide the code of your TextFormField